# Davis-Kahan type results for lower bounds

Tags: linear-algebra, perturbation-theory

I have been working on a problem which requires a lower bounds on the Principal angle between subspaces. Specifically, I was looking for tight lower bounds similar to the Davis Kahan $\sin \theta$ theorem. I have found some basic results for very specific models (the spiked covariance model for PCA, particularly for the rank 1 case) but was wondering if there are any references which apply to more generic Hermitian (even PSD for that matter) matrices

Comment: for those who, like me,  have never heard of any of this, http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~mmahoney/s15-stat260-cs294/Lectures/lecture13-05mar15.pdf  or https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-s997-high-dimensional-statistics-spring-2015/lecture-notes/MIT18_S997S15_Chapter4.pdf

Comment: Thanks, the second link was one of the few references I found (for the lower bound). Particularly, immediately before Theorem 4.8, the author mentions that the theorem holds for general case, but there is no reference, and even more unfortunately, the bibliography is missing altogether.

Comment: [Bibliography](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-s997-high-dimensional-statistics-spring-2015/lecture-notes/MIT18_S997S15_Chapter5.pdf#page=21)

Comment: Thanks Keith. I don't find any relevant references for the part I am interested in though. Thanks anyway.